# get height on a block of latex output

Tags: latex

I am trying to determine how to get the height on a block of latex *output* (*not* the whole document, and *not* the code..but rather a *block* of *output*). As an example of what I am trying to accomplish: i were to have the latex code

```
$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n}>\infty$ \newline hello world \newline hello universe
```

The height of the above block of text is dependent on a number of things-font, margin size, and of course what the text is, as changing any of these parameters changes how many inches that output would be, but with default formatting its output would be something like 2 inches high.

I am hoping there is a package that does this!

Comment: Could you elaborate on the reasons for wanting this? I'm curious what your use for it would be :).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Usually, the trick is to put whatever you want to measure into a box and then simply not typeset the box, but measure it:

```
\newdimen\height
\setbox0=\hbox{\Huge Hello, World!}
\height=\ht0 \advance\height by \dp0
The height is: \the\height
```

Comment: This won't work with \newline. is there a workaround for this, or a different approach?

Thanks in advance!


georg

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry. For multiple lines, use `\vbox` (vertical box) instead.

Comment: this works perfectly. Though, I was wondering where i could find out more about what's going on here.. why do you need \the in \the\height?

danke im Voraus!

Comment: `\the` is a convenient TeX primitive, so the canonical explanation is
in the TeXbook, p.214. A nice online explanation is at http://www-f9.ijs.si/~matevz/docs/tex/cseq.html#the-rp.

Answer (score 12):

I think this will work:

```
\newlength{\somenamehere}
\settoheight{\somenamehere}{\hbox{...}}
```

Where `...` is your content you like to measure. And you can then use `\somenamehere` as the height of that content.

---

Example:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\newlength{\heightofhw}
\settoheight{\heightofhw}{\hbox{Hello World!}}
Value = \the\heightofhw
\end{document}
```

Will output:

> Value = 6.8872pt

---

**Note:**

- Values of lengths are stored as points, and 1 inch ≈ 72.27 pt
- This does not require any additional packages.

**Update:**

Use `\hbox` to correctly calculate the height of a different sized environment, but it won't work with newlines :-(

Comment: I'd add that this trick can't be used (as simple as it is now) to set the dimension passed to `includegraphics` when it typesets a TikZ picture through the `tikzscale` package. That is to say that the command `\includegraphics[width=\somenamehere]{figure.tikz}` doesn't work. Maybe the answerer or some other guru can trim the solution to make it work for this case too.

Comment: Actually the command works as expected, but an error is thrown.