# Obtain latex output height with Python

Tags: python-3.x, latex

I'm using Python to generate .tex files, which then are build by running latexmk in a Python subprocess. Now I want to generate images in Python that fit exactly with the text content on a page. Of course, the size of the text content depends on the amount of text, font, etc. Latex allows me to find this height ([Like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939450/get-height-on-a-block-of-latex-output)), but how would I get that returned to Python?

Comment: You can only know the size of the output once it's typeset. So you'd have to compile the document once to see the size of the output, then generate the image for insertion and then recompile the LaTeX document (at which point the content would change). Can you provide a more tangible view on what you're after? What does your input/output look like?

Comment: Yes exactly :-) Basically I want to make the process you describe automatic, rather than manual. My pages look pretty simple - there is one block of text (title + normal) and then the rest of the page needs to be filled with the image. So I could generate the text bit, show the height of that block on the page, and then manually set my image to be generated to that height. This is of course really tedious and not realistic for large documents. So it'd be great if it were possible to write the block height to a text file and then read it with Python, for example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following TeX file stores the text inside a box - `\mytextbox` - before setting the box within the text block. Once you have the text in a box, you can return the measurements. I write `\the` `h`eigh`t` (in `p`oin`t`s) to a text file `textboxheight.txt`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,newfile}

\newsavebox{\mytextbox}

\begin{document}

\savebox{\mytextbox}{%
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
%\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}% Restore \parindent, if needed
\strut % To achieve the appropriate baseline skip on first line
\lipsum*[1]% A first paragraph of random text

\lipsum*[2]% A second paragraph of random text
\strut % To achieve the appropriate baseline skip on last line
\end{minipage}}

\noindent
\usebox{\mytextbox}

\newoutputstream{boxdim}% Open output stream
\openoutputfile{textboxheight.txt}{boxdim}% Open file to write to
\addtostream{boxdim}{\the\ht\mytextbox}% Write text box height to file
\closeoutputstream{boxdim}% Close output stream

\end{document}
```

At this point, your Python code can read `textboxheight.txt` and do the rest, I'm sure.

It would be possible to output the height in a [different dimension](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8260/5764), if needed.

Comment: At first I couldn't get this to work, but that's because I was using latexmk. With pdflatex it works :-) I only got a lot of extra whitespace, even more so with the extra struts. But that was easy to fix with a negative vspace :-)